# How to control the character length of strings in tcl errors?

Tags: tcl

Long strings which appear in tcl error messages are elided with ... after 150 characters:

```
proc helloWorld {a} {
       throw
}
helloWorld "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"
```

Error:

> ```
> invalid command name "throw"
>     while executing "throw "
>     (procedure "helloWorld" line 2)
>     invoked from within "helloWorld "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff..."
>     (file "mytcl" line 6)
> ```

Is there a way to change this so that more characters are shown?

In my large commercial tcl application, customers use file paths that are more than 150 characters long.  We see 100 characters for a repository name, plus 100 characters for a location within the repository.  Since only 150 characters appear, this means the "useful" part of the filename is not displayed in error messages.  We have suggested to the customer that they could shorten the path using a symlink, but they do not accept this.

Answer (score 2):

You can install your own background error handler.
You can log the error, display it how you want, etc.

```
interp bgerror {} ::bgerrhandler

# give err and res whatever names that make sense to you
proc ::bgerrhandler { err res } {
  # do stuff
  return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you've got is that the line-shortening is applied during the construction of the error trace message. It's already long gone by the time you get to see it. What you need instead is to install a custom background error handler *using the new API* that picks critical things out of the *error stack.* (The old API using a simple `bgerror` command is unsuitable for this task as it hides the result option dictionary for backward compatibility reasons.)

```
proc MyErrorHandler {msg opts} {
    if {[dict get $opts -code] == 1} {
        # Actually an error!
        puts "ERROR: $msg"
        foreach {op details} [dict get $opts -errorstack] {
            puts stderr "$op :> $details"
        }
        return
    }
    # Transfer to standard implementation; tailcall recommended for this from 8.6 on
    ::tcl::Bgerror $msg $opts
}
interp bgerror {} MyErrorHandler
```

Here's an example of this working:

```
# Error generation code
proc foo {x} {throw BOOM $x}
proc bar {y} {foo $y$y$y$y}
proc grill {} {bar skdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsd}
# Now actually do things in the background
after idle grill; after 50 set z 1; vwait z
```

That will print this message:

```
ERROR: skdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsd
INNER :> returnImm skdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsd {-errorcode BOOM}
CALL :> foo skdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsdskdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsd
CALL :> bar skdfhglsdjklfgjhsdlfgjksdlkfhgklsdhfjklghskldfsldfkjghlsd
CALL :> grill
```

The `INNER` indicates what bytecode opcode actually threw, and then there's a sequence of `CALL`s to give the exact arguments lists that lead to that point.